# alternative for SOAP return array dataType

Tags: web-services, visual-studio-2012, soap, yii, zend-framework2

After 4 days of testing and asking in Stack Overflow: [Importing Yii Created Soap Server To Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19469660/importing-yii-created-soap-server-to-visual-studio) this is the results:

**Q:** Why my Yii soap server can not be imported in visual studio?
**A:** Yii uses RPC encoded style for WSDL, while visual studio expects document/literal. So you can use Zend Framework libraries to create a document/literal encoded web server.

**New Issue**: After hours of testing I found out that returning an array in functions creates an error that visual studio can not import it. 
**Is there any alternative for SOAP return array data Type, so visual studio can import WSDL of the server?**

Also I could not a practical example of *implementing a document/literal Zend Framework created soap server in Yii* so I write what I coded, Maybe the others can refer to:

> ***./protected/components/soapTTS.php***

```
<?php

class soapTTS {

    /**
     * @param int $CourseId
     * @return array
     */
    public function ListAllStudentsOnASelectiveCourse($CourseId) {
        $out = helper::ListAllStudentsOnASelectiveCourse($CourseId);
        return $out;
    }


}

?>
```

`* @return array` in above causes the problem.

> ***./protected/controllers/SoapController.php***

```
<?php
class SoapController extends Controller {
    public function actionService() {
        Yii::import('application.vendors.*');
        Yii::setPathOfAlias('Zend', Yii::getPathOfAlias('application.vendors.Zend'));
        if (isset($_GET['wsdl'])) {
            $autodiscover = new Zend\Soap\AutoDiscover(new \Zend\Soap\Wsdl\ComplexTypeStrategy\ArrayOfTypeSequence());
            $autodiscover->setBindingStyle(array('style' => 'document'));
            $autodiscover->setOperationBodyStyle(array('use' => 'literal'));
            $autodiscover->setClass('soapTTS');
            $autodiscover->setUri('http://localhost/millms/mws/soap/service');
            header("Content-type: text/xml");
            echo $autodiscover->toXML();
        } else {
            // pointing to the current file here
            $soap = new Zend\Soap\Server("http://localhost/millms/mws/soap/service?wsdl");
            $soap->setObject(new Zend\Soap\Server\DocumentLiteralWrapper(new soapTTS()));
            $soap->handle();
        }
    }

}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I could not solve the problem exactly, So I returned all array outputs as string and I converted theme to JSON response. So importing process in visual studio is OK and responses are correct too.